# get length of items ngFor async / Observable<Aviso[]>;

Tags: angular, ngfor

How can I get the total number of items using ngFor?

```
*ngFor="let aviso of avisosTest | async; let i = index"
```

I'm working with Firestore from Firebase with an Observable:

```
avisosTest: Observable<Aviso[]>;
```

I tried this but it did not work

```
{{ avisosTest.length }}

{{ avisosTest?.length }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Angular 4 you can do this:

```
*ngFor="let aviso of avisosTest | async as aviso; let i = index"
```

And then you can call `{{ avisosTest.length }}` inside that tag.

Example

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let aviso of avisosTest | async as aviso; let i = index">
    {{aviso}} - {{i + 1}} of {{aviso.length}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-alxees?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html) - wait 2 seconds for data load

If you need it outside of the loop, you can separate `async` and `ngFor`, like:

```
<div *ngIf="avisosTest | async as aviso">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let aviso of aviso; let i = index">
      {{aviso}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    {{aviso.length}} items total
  </div>
</div>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmw2v?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)  - wait 2 seconds for data load

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me the 2nd. I do not know why in the first option I do not get results. But it's what I needed thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
<div *ngIf="(avisosTest | async)?.length==0">No records found.</div>
```

or

```
<div *ngIf="(avisosTest | async)?.length>0">{{avisosTest.legnth}}</div>
```

Comment: It's strange, it does not generate any results

Comment: are you seeing any results on console.log(this.avisosTest);

Comment: Typo it should be `avisosTest.length`

Comment: print console console.log(this.avisosTest) `Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}`

Comment: seems it does not have any data